How do I make my image in a carousel a clickable link?
How do I make each image in my carousel a clickable link to my other pages? I can get them to work outside of my carousel or when I do get them to work within the carousel the sit within the it side by side centered within the carousel.
<div id="drag-container">
<div id="spin-container">
    <img src=""><a href="" alt=""></a>
    <img src=""><a href="" alt=""></a>
    <img src=""><a href="" alt=""></a>
    <img src=""><a href="" alt=""></a>
    <img src=""><a href="" alt=""></a>
    <img src=""><a href="" alt=""></a>
    <img src=""><a href="" alt=""></a>



</div>
<div id="ground"></div>

I have tried moving the image src and <a herf around as well as removing brackets. the closes I can get to what I want was the images to be stuck in the center side by side. I even added a z index, but that did nothing. here is a list of what I have tried so far.
    <a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
    
    <a href="" img src="" alt=""></a>
    
    <img src= "" a href="" alt=""></a>
    <img src= "" href="" alt=""></a>
    <img src= ""><a href="" alt=""></a>
    <a href=""</a><img src="" alt="">

and adding a z inex.

in your code <img> tags and <a> tags are siblings and by clicking on Image tags you won't be able to trigger the <a> tags and links.
So the relation between <a> tags and <img> tags must be a parent-child relation to have clickable images.
Put the image tag inside the <a> tag
like this:
<a href="" alt=""><img src=""></a>

So for each carousel you should have a structure like this:
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <a href="page1.html">
      <img src="image1.jpg" alt="Description 1">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <a href="page2.html">
      <img src="image2.jpg" alt="Description 2">
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- More carousel items -->
</div>

and CSS as well:
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Other carousel styles */
}

.carousel-item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* Other item styles */
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
  /* Ensures images fit their container */
}

